# is an instance variable in an action of a controller available for all the controllers view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am just trying to print the parameters that have been entered into my form.
Basically I create a new bet then I display the parameters:

MIGRATION

```
class CreateBets < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
    create_table :bets do |t|
    t.integer :accepted ,:default => 0
    t.integer :user_1_id #proposer
    t.integer :user_2_id #receiver
    t.integer :team_1_id #proposer's team
    t.integer :team_2_id #receiver's team
    t.integer :game_id
    t.integer :winner
    t.integer :amount
    t.timestamps
   end
 end

  def self.down
    drop_table :bets
  end
end
```

CONTROLLER

bets_controller.erb

```
class BetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to new_bet_path
  end

  def new
    @b=Bet.new
  end

  def create
    @points=params[:points]
    @winner=params[:winner]
  end

end
```

VIEWS
New.erb

```
<% facebook_form_for Bet.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount, :label=>"points" %>
  <%= f.text_field :winner, :label=>"WinningTeam" %>
  <%= f.buttons "Bet" %>
<% end %>
```

create.erb

```
points:<%= @points  %>
<br>
winner:<%= @winner  %>
```

I tried to make this code work with instance variables but it didn't work either. Where is the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `params[:winner]` and `params[:point]` is empty hash. Try adding this to your create.erb:

```
params: <%= params.inspect %>
```

It will display your `params` hash, so you will see how to get to it.

Another hint, why you are creating new object in `new` action and then in form you are doing it again? So:

```
<% facebook_form_for @b   do |f| %>
```

And another thing, it is really good to keep naming conventions, so don't create `@b` object, but `@bet`.

In `create` action you should have line like this:

```
@bet = Bet.new(params[:bet])
```

And in view:

```
<p>
  points:<%= @bet.points %>
</p>
<p>
  winner:<%= @bet.winner %>
</p>
```

If you use `<br>` it's better to use `<br/>`.

Your `index` action is totaly useless. It would be better if you would move all behaviour from `new` action to `index` and remove `new` action completly.

Answer (score 0):

As klew pointed, for me it seems that you're getting empty `params[:winner]`and `params[:point]`. You can make sure that of what you're getting by taking a look at your servers log.

You will see a line like

```
Processing BetsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-11 20:56:51) [POST]
Parameters: {"your"=>"parameters", "should"=>"apper in this hash"}
```